# Swapping 3TB HD to a new computer

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I had an old Dell 7500 Workstation that I had set up as a Ubuntu 18 box.  I have spent a fair amount of time getting it set up to run Openvino.  The Workstation will not run stable anymore. I had another older computer HP Pavilion Elite HPE that I wasn't using so I thought I would attempt to pull the Seagate 3TB HD and see if I could get it to boot on the HP machine. You might have guess what would happen I got an error:
error : attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'.
Entering rescue mode ...
grub rescue >

Grub rescue is a common problem.  I tried what many recommend doing

grub rescue > ls

(hd0) (hd, msdos1)
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos1)/ # This is where Linux is running

grub rescue > set boot=(hd0,msdos1)

grub rescue > set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub

grub rescue > insmod normal

grub rescue > normal

However, when I type in : insmod normal , the same error comes out:

error : attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'.

I hope I am not hosed.  Any thoughts?

Comment: If the drive was amongst other drives in the computer originally, there is a chance `/etc/fstab` is still saying the drive is in the old position. Example: my laptop has /dev/sda as my hard drive, and my SSD as /dev/sdb. If I try to put my hard drive in a different machine, there is a chance it doesn't boot simply because my hard drive is no longer in the same position (/dev/sda). Not sure if this is your issue though.

Comment: doesn't sound like this will work.  Is that what I am hearing from you?  There is no way to point the BIO to the correct position on the HD?

Comment: Best practice when making a significant hardware change is to reinstall the OS.  When you pull a hard drive out of one PC and put it in another, you are essentially changing every piece of hardware.  As long as the hard drive was not the cause of failure on your old system you should be able to mount the drive on another computer so that you can retrieve files, in case you are not caught up on your backups.  You can use a live session for this (Try Ubuntu).  I recommend performing a system installation on the new PC after you do this.

Comment: @thiirane There is a way to fix it: you can find out the position in the new machine, and you can edit `/etc/fstab` and other related things to point to the new position. Big disclaimer however is that it is NOT easy by any means. Edit: You can use `fdisk -l` to find the new disk position, or use `gparted` which might be way easier.

Comment: What is Ubuntu 18 there is no such version.